# How to make the feature clipping by bbox fast in postgis

Tags: postgis

I am using postgis to serve 10+ layers, and the data will be returned by a given bbox and a zoom level.

This is the sql I used for query features:

```
public List<Feature> getFeature(double[] bbox, int zoom){
    List<Feature> features=new ArrayList();
    for(String layer:layers){
        String sql = "SELECT name, ST_Intersection(layer.geom,bbox.geom) as dest_geom FROM layer JOIN (select ST_MakeEnvelope(?, ?, ?, ?, 4326) as geom) bbox ON st_intersects(table_name.geom, bbox.geom) where layer.zoom <= ?";
        ResultSet rs=conn.executeQuery(sql); //

        while(rs.next()){
            Feature f=new Feature();
            f.name = rs.getString("name");
            f.geometry = f.getObject("dest_geom")
        ....
            features.add(f);
        }

    }
    return features;
}
```

Now it will take almost 200ms for a bbox which conver a 512x512 tile in zoom 16, however it will take almost 10s for a bbox which conver a 512x512 tile in zoom 10.

Though the later have a wide range which means more features, however in a small zoom level the visible features is less too, and that is what the `where layer.zoom<=?` condition does.

And I have created index for each layer by following this [docs](http://revenant.ca/www/postgis/workshop/indexing.html):

```
CREATE INDEX layer_gix ON layer USING GIST (geom);
....
```

Is there anything I can do to speedup the query?

---

Update( add explain analyze):

[image]

select no-geometry fields:
[image]

Comment: How many features we are talking about? `ST_Intersection()` may take some time. What is the output of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE [...]`?

Comment: You could add an index for layer.zoom, this may improve a little, though I believe `st_intersection()` is the main problem.

Comment: @RoVo: Total 500k+ points and 70k+ lines and 1200k+ polygons.

Comment: what about the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` output ? Can you update the question with it ?

Comment: +1 for the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`, but also do you really need to return the intersection of your geometries with the bbox ? This will be very CPU intensive, your query would be much faster if you only had `SELECT geom FROM layer WHERE geom && ST_MakeEnvelope(...)`

Comment: Maybe consider using geotools which has a bunch of optimizations for this

Comment: Do the results have to be cut down?  The intersection calculations can be quite expensive.  Finding which features touch a bbox is relatively cheap because of shortcuts, but doing the full intersection not so much.  Of course that depends on the geometries you are looking at and the end purpose

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK PostGIS indexes don't work well when one of the geometries is inlined in the query. I would try to go around that with the CTE:

```
WITH envelope AS (
    select ST_MakeEnvelope(?, ?, ?, ?, 4326) as geom
)
SELECT 
    name, 
    ST_Intersection(layer.geom,envelope.geom) as dest_geom 
FROM layer 
JOIN envelope ON st_intersects(table_name.geom, envelope.geom)
WHERE layer.zoom <= ?;
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried to use `with` instead of inline geometry, however there seems little improvement.

Comment: Weird, could you provide the proper `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`?

Comment: I update that, please have a check if possible.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the query. Why do you use <= instead of =? Are you really looking for multiple zoom levels? Just crossed my mind...

Comment: The `zoom` in the databse actually meas `minzoom` so for a given map zoom, we should return features whose zoom is less than that.

Comment: I see. Out of ideas right now.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the bounding boxes for the join it will greatly speed up the query.

```
WITH envelope AS (
    select ST_MakeEnvelope(?, ?, ?, ?, 4326) as geom
)
SELECT 
    name, 
    ST_Intersection(layer.geom,envelope.geom) as dest_geom 
FROM layer 
JOIN envelope 
ON table_name.geom && envelope.geom
WHERE layer.zoom <= ?;
```